# I want to build the Xcode in command line by enabling 'Generate test coverage files' and 'Instrument program flow'

Tags: xcode4.5

I want to build the Xcode in command line by enabling 'Generate test coverage files' and 'Instrument program flow'
Since i want to do the code coverage from jenkins i want to set the 'Generate test coverage files' and 'Instrument program flow' of XCode to be enabled.
I know the GUI option where to set but i want to run from Terminal since from jenkins it will build thorough the command line

xcodebuild -workspace ../x.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspce -scheme y 
 then what should  i give in the above command to enable the 'Generate test coverage files' and 'Instrument program flow'

Answer (score 2):

Add .xcconfig file to your project with following content

```
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = YES
GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES = YES
```

and run xcodebuild with -xcconfig flag passing it path to your config file